Compartment models with infinite compartments
Compartment models are used in a number of fields. While studying the literature (and especially E. Allen‘s book on Modeling with Itô Stochastic Differential Equations) I have noticed that all the compartment models I come across have a finite number of compartments.
Is there any research or material on compartment models with infinitely many compartments?
One easy example to consider would be looking at a number of compartments indexed by $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{R}$. Can we recover a random walk given suitable transition probabilities?
